# Cannot install http-server on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, httpserver

I've just installed node js from the msi installer. I get this error when i run "npm install http-server –g":

```
C:\dev\workspace_professional_web_development>npm install http-server –g
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\dev\workspace_professional_web_development\–g
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "http-server" "–g"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path C:\dev\workspace_professional_web_development\–g
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\dev\workspace_professional_web_development\–g'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Is this a bug or is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: I changed the command to "npm install -g http-server" and it worked. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

The '–' you're using is incorrect and the source of your error. It appears to be an [EM DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) rather than a hyphen '-'

Note that you can tell the difference visually between the two:
– -

Likely it's a copy&paste error from the website or something similar